# How can I get the correct offset from that instruction?

Tags: memory, game-hacking, cheat-engine

I have the following instructions:

[image]

The registers' values in the **First instruction** are:

- RAX=0000000033307EE0
- RCX=0000000000000000

The registers' values  in the **Second instruction** are:

- RAX=0000000033307EE0
- RCX=00000000377F1FD0

What I did is:

The first instruction offset is `[rax + rcx*8] = RCX(00000000) * 8 =  8`
So, the final result is `Address(33307EE0) + Offset(8)`.

And the second instruction offset is `[rax + rcx*8] = RCX(377F1FD0) * 8 = BBF8FE80`
So, the final result is `Address(33307EE0) + Offset(BBF8FE80)`.

**Are those results true?** because I found the address is correct but the offset is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RAX=0x33307EE0 + RCX=0x0 * 0x8] == [0x33307EE0+0x0] = **`0x33307EE0`**
compare whatever is at Address  **`0x33307EE0`** with r9 register

[RAX=0x33307EE0 + RCX=0x377F1FD0 * 0x8] == [ 0x33307EE0 + 0x1bbf8fe80] = **`0x1ef297d60`**

mov into rcx whatever is there at **`0x1ef297d60`**

you really need to find some reading/viewing material on assembly
it is always better to read a book on subject matter instead of getting random tidbit advice from unknown strangers on a web service if you need to grasp the basics

Comment: At present, I read several books about assembly, although I have seen that form before `[eax+ecx*5]`, etc, but I didn't understand it but after your answer, I understood what it means.

Comment: without you understanding the basics it will be difficult to tell basically you save everything prehand before destroying write new code at same place which does what you want and also what you destroyed and return back to flow it is like joining a tee at two places in a pipe to cut out the leaking part in laymans term